# Best practice to limit modal by time

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-native-elements

I am building a simple quiz app in React Native. When the user gets an answer correct, I would like to show a popup modal (React Native Elements) that says 'Congratz'. I have got this working as follows:

```
<Overlay isVisible={{this.props.showModal}}>
  <Text>Congratz</Text>
</Overlay>
```

Where, showModal is set via a dispatch in my Redux and Redux Thunk action. However, I would like to limit this to only show for 2 seconds and then disappear. What would be the best practice to achieve this?

Currently my thunk action is:

```
export const showModal = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: "SHOW_MODAL" });
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var end = start;
    while (end < start + 2000) {
      end = new Date().getTime();
    }
    dispatch({ type: "HIDE_MODAL" });
  };
};
```

But this locks up the system for 2 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use simple `setTimeout` function for dispatching `HIDE_MODAL`after dispatching `SHOW_MODAL`.

```
dispatch({ type: "SHOW_MODAL" });
setTimeout(() => dispatch({ type: "HIDE_MODAL" }), 2000);
```